# Cordova/Knockout/jQueryMobile cache memory performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I'm using Knockout and jQueryMobile to write an application that I'm publishing using Cordova.  I've written a light framework for intermingling the ko view models and the jqm page elements.  All observables are in viewmodel objects that are nulled on page change, and all ui definition of the pages are using 'with' or 'template' bindings so that knockout cleans it's own listeners and removes the inner dom content of the page before jqm swaps pages.  This way, no bindings are long-lived and the dom should be released as necessary.

When analyzing the heap with the chrome debugger tools, I am still seeing dozens to hundreds of cumulative megabytes leaking as the application is navigated. Most (all?) of the leaked objects are (or are hanging off of) detached dom nodes that are reachable only from the jquery cache.  I would be ok with the memory hit in order to increase performance, however, users are complaining of slowdowns on mobile devices that increase with the length of time using the application.

I would love to simply use a different ui library and cut out jquery entirely, but that's not an option.

1. Is there a way to disable the jquery cache?
2. Is there a way to manually clear the jquery chache?
3. Any other suggestions?

**EDIT:** After some more research, it seems that the issue is related to letting knockout handle the dom manipulation.  jQuery now is holding cached event listeners because it doesn't know that the nodes that are attached to the events are now detached from the DOM. Ironically, my architecture was recently reorganized around the reverse case of knockout keeping references to detach nodes.  It seems that the high level answer is still 'never use two libraries that manipulate the DOM', but I'll keep working towards a less aggressive solution.

Answer (score 0):

The docs say to simply set this to false:

`$.mobile.page.prototype.options.domCache = false;`

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0.1/docs/pages/page-cache.html

FYI - they are not detached DOM nodes, they are actually still in the DOM.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As shown in the docs for the current version, this option is set to false by default and can be enabled if you actually want to hang on to the DOM objects for pages that are not shown: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/pages/.  Pages that are not displayed are removed from the DOM by default. 

My problem is that there are detached dom nodes that are still reachable from jquery's cache.

Comment: You can see your cache directly by logging `$.cache` - whenever I load up a page on the documentation site and look in `$.cache` it has a bunch of elements on the current page, but it is cleared between page navigations.